# How can I use Q promises together with MongoDB cursor.each()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, q

The gist of my code is as follows:

```
function checkWinRate(array){
    var winCount = 0;
    var totalCount = 0;
    db.collection.find(query).each( function(foo){
        if (condition){
            winCount++;
        }
        totalCount++;
        db.close();
    });
    return winCount/totalCount;
}
```

The obvious problem here is that at the return statement, both winCount and totalCount are still equal to 0. I am trying to use Q promise library to sort out a sequence of events, but I am not sure exactly how to implement it. Can anybody tell me what to do with Q?

**EDIT**

ID: 10T Error here. I forgot I was using the monk wrapper. For those who want to know what I did to solve this, monk has a nice way of dealing with promises in the following way:

```
function checkWinRate(array){
    var winCount = 0;
    var totalCount = 0;
    var promise = db.collection.find(query).each( function(foo){
        if (condition){
            winCount++;
        }
        totalCount++;
        db.close();
    });
    promise.success(function(){
        return winCount/totalCount);  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The function you are passing in `each()` will be executed asynchronously. You need to immediately return a promise and resolve it after all the iterations are finished:

```
var deferred = Q.defer();

db.collection.find(query).each(function(err, item) {
    if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
    }

    if (condition){
        winCount++;
    }
    totalCount++;

    if(item == null) {
        // iterations are finished
        deferred.resolve(winCount/totalCount);
        db.close();
    }
});

return deferred.promise;
```

To obtain value you need to call `checkWinRate` this way:

```
checkWinRate(array).then(function (rate) {});
```